# Building wheel for lxml (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

Tags: python, django, docker

I have this error while running docker

Everything works in server but locally lxml finishes with this error:

```
#0 55.92   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/02/f8/c2/4a8e9dce6caefe8931213e951f7d1b19e6a7d86fc2becc228e
#0 55.92   Building wheel for lxml (setup.py): started
#0 57.58   Building wheel for lxml (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
#0 57.60   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 57.60
#0 57.60   × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
#0 57.60   │ exit code: 1
#0 57.60   ╰─> [88 lines of output]
#0 57.60       Building lxml version 4.6.3.
#0 57.60       Building without Cython.
#0 57.60       Building against libxml2 2.9.10 and libxslt 1.1.34
#0 57.60       running bdist_wheel
#0 57.60       running build
#0 57.60       running build_py
#0 57.60       creating build
#0 57.60       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
#0 57.60       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
#0 57.60       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
#0 57.60       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
#0 57.60       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources
#0 57.60       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
#0 57.60       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
#0 57.60       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1   
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1       
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1      
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
#0 57.60       copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
#0 57.60       warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
#0 57.60
#0 57.60       running build_ext
#0 57.60       building 'lxml.etree' extension
#0 57.60       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
#0 57.60       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src
#0 57.60       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/lxml
#0 57.60       gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/lxml/etree.o -w
#0 57.60       src/lxml/etree.c:289:12: fatal error: longintrepr.h: No such file or directory
#0 57.60         289 |   #include "longintrepr.h"
#0 57.60             |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#0 57.60       compilation terminated.
#0 57.60       Compile failed: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
#0 57.60       creating tmp
#0 57.60       cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInitzmdan9ao.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInitzmdan9ao.o
#0 57.60       cc tmp/xmlXPathInitzmdan9ao.o -lxml2 -o a.out
#0 57.60       error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
#0 57.60       [end of output]
```

pyodbc finishes with the similar error:

```
#0 71.15       In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:
#0 71.15       src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
#0 71.15          56 | #include <sql.h>
```

What I tried to do:

1. Cmake 3.25.0 was added to requirements.txt
2. RUN apt-get -y install python3-lxml

RUN apt-get -y install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev

RUN apt -y install libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev

RUN apt-get -y install libgmp3-dev libmpfr-dev

was added to dockerfile

But error is still the same

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install mssql-tools msodbcsql17
RUN apt-get -y install libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev ldap-utils

RUN apt-get -y install python3-lxml
RUN apt-get -y install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev
RUN apt -y install libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev
RUN apt-get -y install libgmp3-dev libmpfr-dev

RUN echo 'export PATH=""' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo 'export PATH=""' >> ~/.bashrc
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

docker-compose.yml:

version: "3.3"

services:

```
db:

  image: postgres
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data4/
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_DB=
    - POSTGRES_USER=
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
web:
  build: .
  command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  environment:
    - PATH=""
    - MSSQL_DB_NAME_KN=
    - MSSQL_DB_NAME_DAPOS=
    - MSSQL_DB_USER=
    - MSSQL_DB_PASSWORD=
    - MSSQL_ADDRESS=
    - MSSQL_PORT=
    - BIND_PASS=
    - POSTGRES_NAME=
    - POSTGRES_USER=
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
  depends_on:
    - db
```

Comment: Solved. I'm using newer version of python